# Reading .csv file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, csv

I am trying to join a .csv file with a .shp file in QGIS but QGIS is unable to read the data in my .csv file as it indicated that the variables are string of length and precision 0. As a result, I am unable to use the method of create a new column of numeric characters and the option to add a new column or to use the field calculator is disable in my attribute table.

Comment: A sample of your data, the exact error message and Qgis Version will go a long way to helping you get an Answer. Please edit you question to include these.

Comment: What did you use to create the CSV file? What platform are you on? If you're on Excel in OS X, try "Windows comma-separated" as a CSV format.

Answer (score 3):

The solution may be to create a .csvt file, in the same folder as your .csv file, where you just write the data type. For instance:

`"String", "String", "String", "String", "String", "Integer"`